# How can I generate html img tags for a folder full of images with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find how to use Automator or AppleScript to generate html `<img>` tags from a directory of images, including the image width and height dimensions.

To do this I need to:

1. select multiple files, limited to images
2. make a loop that goes through each file
3. find dimensions of image
4. build / concatenate a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done applescript, but pieced this together, mostly thanks to an [image events reference](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/01.html). Suggestions welcome.

```
-- select multiple files, limited to images
set filelist to choose file of type "public.image" with multiple selections allowed

set html to ""

-- make a loop that goes through each file
repeat with imagefile in filelist
    tell application "Image Events"
        launch
        set img to open imagefile
        -- get dimensions of image
        copy the dimensions of img to {W, H}
        -- build / concatenate html string
        set html to html & "<img alt=\"\" src=\"" & name of imagefile & "\" width=\"" & W & "\" height=\"" & H & "\" />
"
        close img
    end tell
end repeat

set the clipboard to html
display dialog "html for " & length of filelist & " images copied to the clipboard!"

html
```